# Spreadsheet gem encoding in rails 2 application for importing special dutch character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, spreadsheet

I am working on rails 2 appicacation i have used  Spreadsheet gem and use UTF-8 encoding for the import.

My code is below.

```
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'     
xls = Spreadsheet.open file.path
```

But the problem is it could not import special dutch characters well .
Please Help me.

Comment: Post the result as well, even if it look gibberish to you it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If this comes from Windows, maybe using `.encode("utf-8", "iso-8859-1")` on the string would work (I used this when reading Microsoft SQL server data via ODBC for German characters).

Otherwise maybe post some details and data samples, what you actually expect and how it actually looks in your output.